# PrestaShop 1.7 - product attributes

Tags: attributes, prestashop

In the product list (below the thumbnails/miniatures), I would like to display the product attributes (like on https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko6hc.jpg). Exactly, I mean the available sizes of clothes (its a clothing store). It's about the effect on the https://andzela.com website.

Unfortunately, I can't "discover" my shop until I'm finished. I code html / css / js, although I don't like php a lot. Please help where to look for the appropriate variables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out. For sizes I used the color attribute (change name, value) and the module of products related to different colors. I've edited a few TPL files, added some styles and everything works great.
Peace!